# How to covert date format in react native?

Tags: react-native, date-formatting

1. 

I am woking on react native project want convert date as below

```
2020-04-12 06:02:00

To 

Sun Apr 12 2020 06:02:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I tried with moment as below

```
let momentObj = moment(resultFltLeg.estArrTime)
let showDate = moment(momentObj).format("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z")
```

but getting below result

```
777 Apr Su 2020 06:02:00 'G4T'
```

Please suggest way to convert date in required format.

2.
After conversion i want to assign this date to other date with same format as below

```
myFltLeg.estArrTime = New Date(resultFltLeg.estArrTime);
```

Please let me know if is this correct way of assign one date to other date

```
myFltLeg.estArrTime // Mon Oct 12 2020 16:42:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const form = someday.format("ddd MMM D YYYY, hh:mm:ss ")
```

this will give you everything until the GMT - for that I think you need `moment-timezone` because the option to append z or zz seems deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for help..can you please guide more on moment ..i did not understand what you said.. It would be helpful for me if you provide code

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I just looked at the docs for formatting: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ - here you see all params and what they do. Under timezone there is a deprecated warning wich says to look moment-timezone. I have no experience with moment-timezone myself tho. But if you have some generall moment.js questions I am able to help.

Comment: Also when you try to assign to an array use push directly on the array with the new dateObject or concat to merge 2 arrays together.